# Использование ScrollView вместо ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-scrollview

Есть приложение (чат) в котором нужно сделать отображение сообщений в виде списка. Но не просто отобразить списком `view`-хи с текстом, `view` могут содержать в себе еще картинки + `view` сами по себе могут быть разными. При простом отображении элементов выбор пал бы на `ListView`.  Но нужно не только их отображать но и иметь возможность их видоизменять, анимировать и т.д. Попробовав сделать список через `ScrollView` я столкнулся с проблемой что `ScrollView` притормаживает, как я понял потому что элементы не пересоздаются, а хранятся в памяти! Вопрос: каким образом лучше реализовать нужную задачу, лично я склоняюсь к `ScrollView`,  так как с ним по идее должно быть проще работать, но как можно решить проблему притормаживания, может есть какие то механизмы?

p.s. может кто то знает как подобные задачи реализован в Viber, VK и остальные messanger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не используйте `ScrollView`, со временем он будет тормозить еще больше, по мере добавления `View`. Используйте `RecyclerView`, примеров в сети достаточно. В нем вы можете указывать любые `View` в зависимости от объекта, который вам нужно показать. В добавок "ячейки" в `RecyclerView` которые ушли за экран, `дестроятся`. это экономит память.

**UPD**
У `RecyclerView` можно переопределить метод `getItemViewType()`, и в зависимости от возвращаемого значения в `onCreateViewHolder()` в можете подставлять нужную `View`